# Populating Navigation Properties Collection Lazy

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have two related classes in a one-to-many relationship. I can access the Class property in one of the classes, but not the other.

Here are my classes:

```
 public  class Seccion
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }           
        public string  Nombre { get; set; }   
       public  ICollection<TipoCaracteristica> TiposCaracteristicas;

    }


    public class TipoCaracteristica
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }         
        public int SeccionId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("SeccionId")]
        public Seccion Seccion { get; set; }
        public List<CaracteristicaAdicional> Caracteristicas;
    }
```

With this code i can include the **Seccion** properties

```
 public IQueryable<TipoCaracteristica> GetTipoCaracteristicas
        {
            get { return db.TipoCaracteristicas.Include("Seccion"); }

        }
```

I haven't been able to get a list of **Seccion** that includs the list of **TipoCaracteristicas**. I also need to get the list of **Caracteristicas** for each **TipoCaracteristicas**.

This is what I'm trying

```
public IQueryable<Seccion> GetSecciones
        {
            get { return db.Secciones.Include("TiposCaracteristicas"); }
        }
```

But I get this error:

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType
>   'Seccion' does not declare a navigation property
>   with the name 'TiposCaracteristicas'.

**How can I do this? Can I include the other level too?**

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: is that all you have - any fluent code? could you 'drop' all specific 'naming' for tables etc. and try w/o it (why it says 'Seccionr' when there isn't such, typo). Try to put up a full if possible reproducible model I can check fast.

Comment: I will update the question with a more basic model. But thats all im using, Im using Code First and it just do all the "Magic" but when its not working i get stuck .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is inform Entity Framework that your properties are Navigation Properties by using the `virtual` keyword. You also need to provide the access modifiers:

```
public virtual ICollection<TipoCaracteristica> TiposCaracteristicas { get; set; }
```